# jQuery Popup Overlay not working on Shopify store

Tags: jquery, popup

I am trying to use the following plugin on my shopify store ... http://dev.vast.com/jquery-popup-overlay/

Here is my mark up ...

```
<div id="my-popup">
<h1>hello</h1>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
{{ 'jquery.popupoverlay.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#my-popup').popup();
});
</script>
```

Chrome webtools keeps giving me an error though ... $(...).popup is not a function

Thought this was pretty straight forward but it;s not working the way it should. I put a fiddle up and it's working there.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: i have the same issue as well on shopify

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to include popup script

just after jquery script

and add an optional button to open popup

So your HTML should be like this

```html
<button class="my_popup_open">Open popup</button>
<div id="my_popup">
 <h1>hello</h1>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/vast-engineering/jquery-popup-overlay/1.7.13/jquery.popupoverlay.js"></script>
{{ 'jquery.popupoverlay.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#my_popup').popup();
});
</script>
```